# The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead of preg_replace()

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I recenlythave tried to convert the preg_replace() line to preg_replace_callback, but with no success. I did try the methods on Stackoverflow, but they seem to be different.

Hope I could get some help with it.

```
function ame_process_bbcode(&$parser, &$param1, $param2 = '')
{
    if (class_exists('vB_BbCodeParser_Wysiwyg') AND is_a($parser, 'vB_BbCodeParser_Wysiwyg'))
    {
     return $text; 
    }
    else
    {
        global $vbulletin;
        ($hook = vBulletinHook::fetch_hook('automediaembed_parse_bbcode_start')) ? eval($hook) : false;
        $ameinfo = fetch_full_ameinfo();

        $text = preg_replace($ameinfo['find'], $ameinfo['replace'], ($param2 ? $param2 : $param1), 1);

        ($hook = vBulletinHook::fetch_hook('automediaembed_parse_bbcode_end')) ? eval($hook) : false;
        return $text;   
    }
}
```

**Updates:** Thanks to @Barmar,  I know now that the issue is related to the **fetch_full_ameinfo** function.. I will add function below. Maybe it will help others in the long run. I will also include the fix whenever I am done. Thanks to @Barmar for the help.

```
function &fetch_full_ameinfo($findonly = false, $refresh = false)
{

    global $db, $vbulletin, $vbphrase, $stylevar;
    static $ameinfo = array();
    static $inied, $lastfind;

    if ($refresh)
    {

        $inied = false;

    }

    if ($lastfind && !$findonly)
    {

        $inied = false;
        $ameinfo = array();

    }

    if (!$inied)
    {

        if (!$refresh AND $vbulletin->options['automediaembed_cache'])
        {

            $path = $vbulletin->options['automediaembed_cache_path'];

            if (file_exists($path . "findonly.php"));
            {

                if ($findonly)
                {

                    include($path . "findonly.php");

                }
                else
                {

                    include($path . "ameinfo.php");

                }

                $inied = true;
                $lastfind = $findonly;

                return $ameinfo;
            }

        }

        if ($vbulletin->options['automediaembed_resolve'])
        {

            $embed = ",IF(extraction=1 AND embedregexp!= '', embedregexp, '') as embedregexp, IF(extraction=1 AND validation!= '', validation, '') as validation";
            $embedwhere = " AND ((extraction = 0 AND embedregexp = '') OR (extraction = 1)) ";

        }
        else
        {

            $embedwhere = " AND embedregexp = ''";

        }


        $sql = "SELECT findcode" . (!$findonly ? ", replacecode,title,container,ameid" : ",extraction$embed") . " FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "automediaembed WHERE status=1 $embedwhere
                        ORDER BY displayorder, title ASC";

        $results = $db->query_read_slave($sql);

        while ($result = $db->fetch_array($results))
        {

            if ($result['findcode'])
            {

                if (!$findonly)
                {

                    $ameinfo['find'][] = "~($result[findcode])~ie";
                    $ameinfo['replace'][] = 'ame_match_bbcode($param1, $param2, \'' . $result['ameid'] . '\', \'' . ame_slasher($result['title']) . '\', ' . $result['container'] . ', \'' . ame_slasher($result['replacecode']) . '\', \'\\1\', \'\\2\', \'\\3\', \'\\4\', \'\\5\', \'\\6\')';


                }
                else
                {

                    $ameinfo['find'][] = "~(\[url\]$result[findcode]\[/url\])~ie";
                    $ameinfo['find'][] = "~(\[url=\"?$result[findcode]\"?\](.*?)\[/url\])~ie";
                    $ameinfo['replace'][] = 'ame_match("\1", "", ' . intval($result['extraction']) .', "' . ($result['embedregexp'] ? "~" . ame_slasher($result['embedregexp']) . "~sim" : "") . '", "' . ($result['validation'] ? "~" . ame_slasher($result['validation']) . "~sim" : "") . '",$ameinfo)';
                    $ameinfo['replace'][] = 'ame_match("\1", "\2", ' . intval($result['extraction']) .', "' . ($result['embedregexp'] ? "~" . ame_slasher($result['embedregexp']) . "~sim" : "") . '", "' . ($result['validation'] ? "~" . ame_slasher($result['validation']) . "~sim" : "") . '", $ameinfo)';

                }

            }

        }

        $inied = true;
    }

    $lastfind = $findonly;

    return $ameinfo;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that uses `preg_replace_callback`?

Comment: If you tried to convert it, why haven't you shown the result of your attempt, so we could tell you what you did wrong? How do you expect to learn from your mistakes?

Comment: Huh? You can clearly see that trying to get help with it. It doesn't matter how my attempts are made, because they were all wrong. I tried 20 different methods. You dont want me to post them all?

Comment: We want you to post something that shows what you tried, probably the one you think should be closest to correct. Otherwise we're just writing it for you, not helping you fix your error.

Comment: Your old code doesn't show the regexp or the replacement. How are we supposed to know what the callback function should do?

Comment: But I've reopened the question. You're using dynamic regexp and replacement, which is different from the hard-coded replacement in the linked question.

Comment: Where does `$ameinfo` come from? Show an example of the contents.

Comment: Barmar thank you for making that point. I keep comparing it to the Regex methods. The function itself was too long. So I tried to shorten it, in order not to confuse any. That make sense.

Comment: The linked question shows how to do it with a hard-coded replacement string. You just need to put a similar anonymous function into `$ameinfo['replace']`.

Comment: The change needs to be made in the code that fills in `$ameinfo['replace']`.

Comment: Ok, I got the whole addon which is made for vBulletin. I will definitely work on it asap. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: If this is coming from a third-party library, you might check whether there's an update that deals with this.

Comment: About the addon itself, its actually outdated on vBulletin.org and the Developer stopped releasing other updates. Its called "AME - Auto Media Embedding". Its a great addon. The issues started when I Upgraded to PHP 5.6. But now I can see what the issues is related to. Its within the " &fetch_full_ameinfo". Thanks to you, I wouldn't have figured that out by myself. so again. Thank you Barmar.

Comment: @Barmar, I have included the &fetch_full_ameinfo above. Hopefully it could help others in the long run. Cheers.

Comment: Ugh, this looks really tricky. The replacement uses `$param1` and `$param2`, but they're not available in the scope of `fetch_full_ameinfo()`.

Comment: lol right. Now you know why I was lost hahah. Thank you so much for the awesome work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put the replacement function in `fetch_full_ameinfo()`, because it needs to refer to the `$param1` and `$param2` variables, which are local to this function.

This means it needs to use `eval()` in the current function (this is essentially what `preg_replace()` does internally when it processes the `/e` flag).

You need to change the replacement string that `fetch_full_ameinfo()` creates so that it uses a variable instead of `\1`, `\2`, etc. to refer to the capture groups, because the callback function receives the captured matches as an array. So replace the block beginning with `if (!$findonly)` with this:

```
if (!$findonly)
    {

        $ameinfo['find'][] = "~($result[findcode])~i";
        $ameinfo['replace'][] = 'ame_match_bbcode($param1, $param2, \'' . $result['ameid'] . '\', \'' . ame_slasher($result['title']) . '\', ' . $result['container'] . ', \'' . ame_slasher($result['replacecode']) . '\', \'$match[1]\', \'$match[2]\', \'$match[3]\', \'$match[4]\', \'$match[5]\', \'$match[6]\')';


    }
else
    {

        $ameinfo['find'][] = "~(\[url\]$result[findcode]\[/url\])~i";
        $ameinfo['find'][] = "~(\[url=\"?$result[findcode]\"?\](.*?)\[/url\])~i";
        $ameinfo['replace'][] = 'ame_match("$match[1]", "", ' . intval($result['extraction']) .', "' . ($result['embedregexp'] ? "~" . ame_slasher($result['embedregexp']) . "~sim" : "") . '", "' . ($result['validation'] ? "~" . ame_slasher($result['validation']) . "~sim" : "") . '",$ameinfo)';
        $ameinfo['replace'][] = 'ame_match("$match[1]", "$match[2]", ' . intval($result['extraction']) .', "' . ($result['embedregexp'] ? "~" . ame_slasher($result['embedregexp']) . "~sim" : "") . '", "' . ($result['validation'] ? "~" . ame_slasher($result['validation']) . "~sim" : "") . '", $ameinfo)';

    }
```

Then change your code to:

```
    $text = preg_replace_callback($ameinfo['find'], function($match) use (&$param1, &$param2, &$ameinfo) {
        return eval($ameinfo['replace']);
    }, ($param2 ? $param2 : $param1), 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar. You a Rock Star